# How to add scroll feature in my HTML page?

Tags: html, css

I want to put this:

[image]

on my website:

[image]

What code should I add? I found this piece of code but it didn't work for me:

```
<td nowrap align="left" style="word-wrap: break-word"><pre style="width:initial !important; margin-left: -25px;">
```

Thank you very much and excuse me for my English

Comment: I think it is a css problem..... you have to look something like word-wrap, overflow properties.... [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS3) you'll find a good tutorial about css3

Comment: css `overflow:scroll` and fixed width/height of the containing container.

Comment: Do you have tried applying the word wrap directly on the pre tag? ^^... Not sure why you are using td and pre :) It should be enough with one of both but not sure becouse there is only a code snippet :)

Comment: Nothing, i not can :(

Comment: Tables fit there width depending on there content. If you want to change this behaviour maybe you should try with display:block. Or using directly divs. Overflow scroll will still apllying it to the x scroll becaouse it is one big line of word. Also you can try applying white-space: pre-wrap; to the pre tag.  Could you maybe post more code? Becouse now it is more like looking inside a magic ball which tell us the future :D

Comment: The part of code that modifies that attribute is this: 

echo '</pre></td>
    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td nowrap align="left"><pre style="width:755px !important; margin-left: -25px; overflow:hidden!important;">
 ';
            
            for($i = 0; $i <= $linea; $i++){

Comment: there still the problem the td :) It has an "display: table-cell" behavoiur. Table, tbody and tr have similar display behaviours wich will be a problem. And at leats the pre wrap which need the     white-space: pre-wrap; :)

Comment: You can try to apply to all this elements (table,tbody,tr,td) the display block behaviour. And at leat give the pre tag the white-space: pre-wrap behaviour. But i have  to mention that that  is not a clean way. **It is just for debugging the problem** And i see there is a "nowrap" in your td :)

Comment: Thanks anyway boys the mine not is the code i will pass

Comment: Don't pass! :D Keep it on (Ningun maestro se ha caido del cielo)

Answer (score 2):

As said, adding `overflow:scroll` in your CSS is an option.

But I would go for `auto` instead of `scroll` in order to hide the scrollbar when the content is not clipped. That's a decision to take depending on the design you want.

Answer (score 1):

Set the overflow property in css of that div or td tag to scroll

overflow:scroll
or you can do
overflow: auto

Comment: <td overflow:scroll nowrap align="left" style="word-wrap: break-word"><pre style="width:auto; margin-left: -25px;">

Answer (score 0):

Set `overflow:auto` to div. so the div scroll come if content size more than div width.